# Modifying XML file directly using java

Tags: java, xml, file

I have an XML file which looks some thing like

```
<words>
<e lm="aBAgA"><i>aBAg</i><par n="kAl/A__adj"/></e> 
<e lm="aBAgA"><i>aBAg</i><par n="ladak/A__n"/></e>
</words>
```

I want to modify the xml file itself to look something like

```
<words>
<e lm="abcd"><i>abcd</i><par n="abcd__adj"/></e>
<e lm="efgh"><i>efgh</i><par n="efgh__n"/></e>
</words>
```

I need a java code for it. I am able to make the changes, but those changes dont get written to the file words.xml.

Thanks

Comment: Do you write the DOM back out?

Comment: Take a look at [STAX API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP3.html)

Comment: i want to avoid using additional apis, is it possible to achieve? basically im just modifying the xml file

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [Java Xpath Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html)